# How do I earn Reaper Energy?

Tags: darksiders-2

Once you hit level 6 in Darksiders, you unlock Reaper Form (You know, that thing you've been transforming into in the boss kill cinematics?), which is powered by Reaper Energy.

Great! So how do we earn Reaper Energy to recharge the ability? The in-game tooltip mentions that you need to use Reaper Attacks to gain Reaper Energy... and then totally fails to explain what a Reaper attack actually is.

So what is Reaper Energy, and how can you acquire it? I've seen a few Wrath skills mention it, and a few weapons have +reaper energy on execute, but I don't have access to those things yet, so I need a way to accrue Reaper Energy in the mean time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, there are weapons which give you reaper energy on attack, on kill, on critical hit or on execute. Those are not (only) end game items. I've had one for level 10 or somewhat which gave me energy on kill. In addition you can equip the talisman from the shaman in the first land (you can get it on a side quest where you have to collect 3 materials. The weapons are  just Lucky drops, so good farming.

I found additional Information in the [IGN Game Guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/darksiders-2/Combat). It seems that the killing of enemies with scythes gets you also reaper energy.

While Testing I discovered that you gain reaper energy on every hit on an enemy with your scythes. In addition, it seems that you gain more on kills (it is difficult to say, cause  I don't have any log file...)

To answer your entire question:

- You gain reaper energy on every Hit with your scythes.
- You gain more reaper energy on a kill with your scythes.
- You can increase the amount of reaper energy received with stats on your weapon or the Grim Talisman
- You won't gain any reaper energy with other weapons than scythes.

Comment: That's all well and good, but it doesn't answer the question - I know it's possible to gain reaper energy *without* those things, because my Reaper Energy bar has been filling up over time. I just don't know *why*.

Comment: As you see in my Edit, you gain additional reaper energy on kill with scythes.

Comment: That makes *more* sense, but since I've been building Reaper Energy off of the training posts in Tristone I think that's *still* not the full story.

Comment: Ok, i've tested it now. You gain reaper energy on every hit when you dealing damage with the scythes. The other weapons don't make anything (without the Talisman and stats) it seems that you gain more on kills.

Comment: One final question - does Grim Talisman let you gain reaper energy from secondary weapons?

Comment: yes it does give you reaper energy on hit with secondary weapons

Answer (score 2):

From what I have found after hitting a training posts for about 5 minutes or so, with my secondary weapon (a level 9 axe with 227-253 damage + 48 lightning damage) on an empty reaper energy bar (the spiral to the left of your health, wrath, and xp bars). The secondary weapon wielded no reaper energy. Then with my scythes (Possessed double scythes with no reaper energy bonus) I could already see it going up after a few hits.

I then equipped the Grim Talisman, and tried again. The reaper energy bar filled slightly with each hit of my axe, and even more so with my scythes.

So as far as I can tell, the Grim Talisman's only purpose is to help boost reaper energy.

And of course once you have an image of a grim reaper instead of the spiral you can hit Lb + Rt at any time to become Death's true form.

Answer (score 1):

You get Reaper Energy by dealing damage with Death's scythes

Comment: I think it's a little more complicated than that, as that's the ability provided by the Grim Talisman item. I don't think it likely that there'd be an equippable item with no real effect.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get better reaper energy builds if you "upgrade" a possessed weapon by "sacrificing" items that have reaper energy. when you sacrifice items to possessed weapons they will have a higher chance of gaining that attribute, but it doesn't matter how high the reaper energy of the item is, so just sacrifice lame items that only have "reaper energy on execute" in order to make sure you get the attribute.

Comment: If you have a different question hit the Ask Question button. This place is reserved for answers.