# How do I earn Reaper Energy if I've sold my Grim Reaper Talsiman?

Tags: darksiders-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I earn Reaper Energy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81100/how-do-i-earn-reaper-energy)

In Darksiders 2, how do I earn reaper energy? I unknowingly sold the Grim Reaper talisman (or I haven't encountered it) I don't have any item that have stats in the form of "Reaper Energy ^"

Comment: [How do i earn reaper energy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81100/how-do-i-earn-reaper-energy)

Comment: It isn't specific to my question. That question merely asks how to earn it. I'm asking how to earn it, IF I don't have that item!

Comment: @AbhishekSha The answer to the other question covers more than just the Talisman, though.

Comment: `You gain reaper energy on every Hit with your scythes` is one of the ways mentioned in the answers on that post. Perhaps you should have taken two minutes to actually read through the post.

Comment: Are you using a special scythe? One of the named, legendary scythes?

Comment: I am using a Shadow of Death Scythes. In the inventory, it's outlined with yellow.

Comment: Try switching to a regular scythe, and see if that will generate reaper energy. I read somewhere that some named scythes do not generate reaper energy.

Comment: Let me know if that works, and I'll put it as the answer.